# Java graphics library with methods to capture mouse evens on drawn objects

Tags: java, graphics, mouseevent

I am looking for a java library that can draw lines and shapes (2d) as well as be able to capture the mouse events on the drawn objects. I will also need the ability to zoom and out on the drawn objects.

I might be asking for a lot but anything close will save me some time re-inventing the wheel.

P.S. It will be even better if the library renders the shapes as objects.

Thanking you all in anticipation.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer will be: 
[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org) .
There you have an access to OpenGL, OpenCL, and OpenAL libraries.

Comment: Out of all of them the one that comes close is probably OpneGL. Yet I am not looking for 3D but only 2D. I do not know if OpenGL will still do it for me.

Comment: It will. It supports both 2D and 3D.